# Drag and drop files in Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, drag-and-drop, python-3.7

I am fairly new to Python and is stuck at a problem. I am using Python 3.7 and intend to add a "drag-and-drop" functionality to my GUI.
I have some files that needs to be read, thus i am looking for an option where i can simply drag those files to a particular area in my GUI and file name or Path is read by my program.

Being a newbie a detailed answer or a code would be highly helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this can help you [cpython/Lib/tkinter/dnd.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tkinter/dnd.py)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, tkinter only supports *experimental* widget drag and drop, nothing else. I ran into similar problems trying to make a complex GUI.

I would look into wxPython. It's complex, Object Oriented, and daunting, but has and unbelievable amount of features that reward you for learning it. Including file drag and drop.

Look at the wxPython thumbnails at https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/gallery.html for images of what the widgets look like. The thumbnails include images for about half of the available widgets. The images are also a bit out of date.

Look at pronounced https://pythonlibrary.org or https://zetcode.com for the best tutorials. After them, your best resource is Google and the forums.